# an array of ArrayControllers

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm doing something wrong here, but can't figure out what. I'm new to both Ember and Javascript in general, so feel free to point out any mistakes. I would appreciate an additional pair of eyes.

I basically have a google map with multiple datasets. In the controller that goes with the view I get the datasets and create an dataSetController(ArrayController) for each dataset. I then let the dataSetController load the data and add it to it's content, and an additional marker array.
When the process is done however, both dataSetControllers contain all points, instead of just the points for the particular dataset.

Below is the controller that goes with the view:

```
App.MapviewShowController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  dataSets: [],

  createDataSets: function() {
    'use strict';

    var self = this;

    // clean previous data
    this.get('dataSets').length = 0;

    $.ajax({
      url: '/active_data_sets.json',
      type: 'GET',
      data: {'project_id': this.get('id')},
      success: function(data) {
        data.active_data_sets.forEach(function(entry) {

          // create a new controller for this dataset
          var newds = App.AddressRecordController.create();
          self.get('dataSets').pushObject(newds);
        });
      },
      error: function() {
      }
    });
  }
});
```

And the dataSetController itself:

```
App.AddressRecordController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({

  content: [],
  isActive: true,
  dataSetId: 0,
  markerColor: '',
  datasetName: '',
  map: null,
  map_nelat: null,
  map_nelng: null,
  map_swlat: null,
  map_swlng: null,
  markerIcon: null,
  markers: [],
  mapBinding: 'App.MapData.map',
  map_nelatBinding: 'App.MapData.ne_lat',
  map_nelngBinding: 'App.MapData.ne_lng',
  map_swlatBinding: 'App.MapData.sw_lat',
  map_swlngBinding: 'App.MapData.sw_lng',

  getAddresses: function(ne_lat, ne_lng, sw_lat, sw_lng) {
    "use strict";

    var self = this;

    $.ajax({
      url: '/address_records.json',
      type: 'GET',
      data: {'dataset_id': this.get('dataSetId'), 'ne_lat': ne_lat, 'ne_lng': ne_lng, 'sw_lat': sw_lat, 'sw_lng': sw_lng},
      success: function(data) {
        data.address_records.forEach(function(new_address) {
          if (!self.findProperty('id', new_address.id)) {
            // add to the content
            self.content.addObject(App.AddressRecord.create(new_address));

            // add the marker
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
              position: new google.maps.LatLng(new_address.lat, new_address.long),
              map: self.get('map'),
              animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
              title: 'marker',
              id: new_address.id
            });

            // add the marker for later reference
            self.markers.push(marker);
          }
        });
      },
      error: function() {
      }
    });
  },

  newBounds: function() {
    "use strict";

    this.getAddresses(this.map_nelat, this.map_nelng, this.map_swlat, this.map_swlng);
  }.observes('map_swlng'),

  clean: function() {
    'use strict';

    // clean the objects in arracycontroller
    this.forEach(function(el) {
      el.destroy();
    });

    // clean the markers
    this.markers.length = 0;
  },

  showMarkers: function() {
    'use strict';

    var self = this;

    if(this.get('isActive')) {
      this.markers.forEach(function(mkr) {
        mkr.setMap(self.get('map'));
      });
    } else {
      this.markers.forEach(function(mkr) {
        mkr.setMap(null);
      });
    }
  }.observes('isActive')
});
```

### Update

AFter further debugging I found out that multiple AddressRecordControllers share nothing except the `markers array`. To circumvent the issue I now store the markers as content and that works fine. Still not clear about why the markers array is shared over different controllers.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the create methods is more like a singleton so it either creates the object or returns a pointer to the object.  So you are just adding to the same controller.  you might try instead.  Ember also has a Mixin thing that I am not sure how it works yet either.

```
var newds = App.AddressRecordController.extend();
```

Comment: I see what you mean, but extend() gave a big error as soon as I start assigning values to it, it's clearly not created.